# Read XML from PHP - JQUERY AJAX POST - Not using XMLHTTP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I got some code off a tutorial a couple of months ago that I am now changing and using in my site. I have already coded alot so do not want to go another route.

Basically I need to retrieve all posts from a database and display on screen dynamically without refreshing the page. now I have the XML that is generated from the PHP file - all is good. Where I am stuck is reading that XML o the ajax side. here is what I have so far:

```
function getAllPosts() {
alert('hi');
var count = 0;
var tlu = getUrlVars()["user"]; // tlu stands for time line user
var data = 'user='+tlu;
$.ajax({
    url: 'getAllPosts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(response){
        var xml = response.responseXML;
        var posts = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("post_item");
        for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var id = posts[i].getAttribute("id");
            var account_name = posts[i].getAttribute("account_name");
            var author = posts[i].getAttribute("author");
            var type = posts[i].getAttribute("type");
            var data = posts[i].getAttribute("data");
            var postdate = posts[i].getAttribute("post_date");
            categoryPost(id, account_name, author, type, data,     postdate);
        }
    }
});
}

function categoryPost(id, account_name, author, type, data, pastdate){
if(type === 'write'){
    alert("hello");
}
}
```

It is running the `alert("hi");` test but not the rest of the code.

My console gives me this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined`

How can I read the elements from the xml? Everywhere I look has that XMLHTTP stuff and I don't, so I am pretty confused...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting an XML response, try setting data type: 'xml'. In your $.ajax parameters. If you're still having issues. Log the response object by using console.log(response) to examine what is actually being returned or you can use Chrome's postman extension. Comes in handy ;-).